# Static Synchronized method provides Class level lock. What does Class Level Lock means?

Tags: java, multithreading, static, locking

Does it mean that any Thread irrespective of the object it obtain will not interfere other Thread executing in Synchronized static method. Even if we call with class_name.static_Method.

```
Ex- If we have two thread :

public class Test implements Runnable {

  public synchronized static testMethod(){}

  public void run(){ testMethod(); }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   Test obj1=new Test();
   Test obj2=new Test();
   Thread t1=new Thread(obj1);
   Thread t2=new Thread(obj2);
   t1.start(); // thread on object obj1
   t2.start(); // Thread on object obj2
   Test.testMethod(); // main thread
}
}
```

If Thread t1 enters static method then t2 and main thread will not enter the method even though both have different object.
Correct me If I am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If Thread t1 enters static method then t2 and main thread will not enter the method even though both have different object*

its a `static` method, which is a ***class level*** (common) method to all the instances (objects) of that class, hence, objects doesn't matter. If its declared as `synchronized`, then the Thread which will execute the method will acquire the lock on the class object (`Class<Test>` object)

a `static synchronized` method can be thought of like below

```
public static testMethod(){
   synchronized(Test.class) {
      //method body
   }
}
```

Since a class gets loaded once (unless you define your custom class-loader and re-load the class), there will be only one class object, which acts as lock for mutual exclusion

Comment: Does it mean that If Thread t1 enters static synchronized block then t1 will acquire two locks one for object obj1 and second for class object.

Comment: What does Class.class mean? Can we write that in place of Test.class.

Comment: No.. there is no necessity to acquire lock on object, in that case `t1` will only acquire lock on the class object. Since there is only one class object per class, when `t1` is executing the `static synchronized` method, no other thread will be allowed to execute (mutual exclusion)

Comment: If program includes Thread t3=new Thread(obj1) then Thread t1 will acquire two locks one for object obj1 and second for class object.

Answer (score 3):

You're thinking about this all wrong.  Don't write this:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    static synchronized SomeType testMethod() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Write this instead.  It means exactly the same thing, but it reveals what's going on:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    static SomeType testMethod() { synchronized(Test.class) {...} }
    ...
}
```

Then, all you need to know is that Test.class is a unique object (it's the object that holds the description of your Test class), and of course, no two threads can ever synchronize on the same object at the same time.

Same thing goes for synchronized instance methods:  This,

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    synchronized SomeType testMethod() { ... }
    ...
}
```

Means the same thing as

```
public class Test implements Runnable {
    SomeType testMethod() { synchronized(this) {...} }
    ...
}
```

But the second one shows you what's really going on.

Answer (score 0):

T1 and T2 are synchronizing on Object `Test.class`. Remember classes are Objects of type `java.lang.Class`

Comment: What does Class.class mean? Can we write that in place of Test.class

Comment: Class.class means an Object of class java.lang.Class.Why do u want to schnchronize on it.

Comment: I just want to know that if I replace Test.class with Class.class will it be logically correct.