# In java, possible side effects of synchronizing on ClassName.class instead of on instance of a class?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, synchronization, static-methods

My understanding is that to synchronize on ClassName.class say Penguin.class may not be the correct way always (i mean using Penguin.class as a normal intrinsic lock, unless intentional to effect the static access of Penguin.class)  and instead preferred way to synchronize would be on penguin (a instance of Penguin.class). 
If i use the former approach i see blocking all the Penguin's static methods for a while (so unless intentional this should be avoided).
Will the former approach also block reads and writes to static fields (think not)? 
Are there any other side effects which I am missing? Performance etc??

Comment: Synchronizing on a `Class` instance blocks all other code which is synchronizing on the same class instance. Nothing more, no different from synchronizing on any other instance.

Comment: You are thinking at too low a level.  Multithreaded code is hard to write, even for smart people.  You're better off using the new concurrency package and thinking in terms of immutable data.  A more functional approach will be far safer and easier to get right.  Letting a thread alter mutable static fields is begging for trouble.  I'd rethink it.

Comment: @duffymo - i can't decide the language for this application, it already done but never gets dusted. some or the other thing breaks ever.  Have n't done much FP, but does it support multi-threading in general and does scala support it.

Comment: You have the Java tag; I assume you want Java.  Does FP support multi-threading?  Um, usually.  Not required.  Scala is a hybrid functional/object-oriented language.  Java itself has lots more functional features since JDK 8 added lambdas.

Comment: Penguin.class is not the same as Class.class.

Comment: @duffymo, the app is mostly  in java, but there is a scala code base also given Apache spark works best with scala (to little extent) . don't know if java 8 can replace this code base with it's lamdas... i will work on spark after finishing with some functionality on this app. If J8 can fill the functional gap with Spark then i will be forced to live with java multi-threading, so it is better to know about both the worlds

Comment: @EJP - got it. Class<T> is a class by itself in java.. editing to reflect same.

Comment: @duffymo using the `java.util.concurrent` libraries does not inherently make your application threadsafe, and it's very dangerous to tell a novice developer (not saying the OP is necessarily, just in general) to use the `java.util.concurrent` libraries and avoid doing locking manually. It is very easy to use the standard classes unsafely. 'Pre-optimization' may be silly on something like a 10k line program, but when you start to get into the millions I think it's silly to think that you could ever overthink a problem.

Comment: Agreed, they do not guarantee anything.  But they're far better than raw Threads and synchronizing on your own.  I see little or no good thinking in the question.  No indication about the size of the program.  I sincerely doubt that this question implies the OP could produce millions of lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will the former approach also block reads and writes to static fields (think not)?

Synchronization *never* blocks reads or writes to *any* field (static or otherwise).  The only thing that synchronization blocks is, it blocks other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.

In order to know what object to synchronize on, it is necessary to understand why you want to synchronize.

You generally want to synchronize because you have a data structure, and you have one or more threads that want to modify the data structure, and it is not possible for any one thread to do its work without temporarily putting the structure into a bad state.  So, you solve that problem by making sure that every thread that modifies the structure only does so while synchronized, and you also make sure that every thread that even *looks at* the structure only does so while synchronized.

So, what to synchronize on?

Well, how many of these data structures are there in your program?  If there is only one of them, then you should have only one synchronization object.  `Foobar.class` is an object that there generally will be only one of in your program, so synchronizing on a Class object often is a good choice when you're protecting global data.

If there are many similar structures, then it often makes sense for each one to have its own independent lock object.  That way, two threads can operate on two different instances at the same time, and they only block each other if they try to operate on the same instance.

If your structures are each represented by an instance of the `Foobar` class, then the simplest way to do it is to synchronize on the foobar instance.  A more sophisticated way to do it is for each `Foobar` object to have its own `private` lock object:

```
class Foobar {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    ...

    public SomeType someOperation(...) {
        ...
        synchronized(lock) {
             doSomethingThatNeedsProtection();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: synchronizing on Foobar.class will block all the static methods in Foobar.class . Right??

Comment: @samshers, No.  It will not block any methods.  The only thing that synchronizing ever blocks is, it blocks other threads from synchronizing on the same object or class at the same time.  (Note:  When you write a synchronized _method_, that's just a shorthand way of writing a method whose body is a synchronized _statement_.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642642/static-synchronized-method-provides-class-level-lock-what-does-class-level-lock/25644342#25644342)

Comment: what about mutual exclusion. ...  i missed adding *synchronized* i.e. static synchronized methods, then I hope these methods get blocked. Right??

Comment: @samshers, "mutual exclusion" (a.k.a., "mutex")  is exactly what I meant when I said, "... blocks other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time."  As for synchronized _methods_, have a look at the link in my previous comment:    Adding `synchronized` to a method declaration is just a shortcut for wrapping the method body in a big `synchronized` _statement_.  Once you understand what a `synchronized` statement does and doesn't do, then synchronized methods are easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A Class is essentially an Object of which there is only one in the runtime.

Class T is an Object(instance) of Class

Class level locking will prevent multiple threads entering the a synchronized block where it is used and so similar to where locking on an 'Object'.